# Magento attribute dropdown values(Yes/No) prints (numeric values)

Tags: magento-1.9

I created an Attribute of type dropdown. I assigned two values of "Yes" & "No". While printing those attributes values, while comparing products i get the values like "133" / "134" . Is it because of systems predefined value or what it is ? How can i get the same value as i assigned for options "Yes" or "No" get printed as attribute value?

**Note :** I tried attribute type 'yes/no' , this prints '1' and ' ' (this will not be clear to visitors/customers).

The code below prints the numeric value for only **dropdown** *attribute type* where as its working nicely for **input field** *attribute type*

```
$valueattr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getId(), $_attribute->getAttributeCode(), $storeId);
```

Comment: please write the code you have tried which prints the numeric value..

Comment: @Dexter , yes i updated with code.

Comment: @Marius has already answered your question.. enjoy !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAttributeRawValue` prints the actual value stored in the db. And yes/no attributes are kept as `0` and `1`.
Try using:

```
$valueLabel = $_item->setStoreId($storeId)->getAttributeText($_attribute->getAttributeCode());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `getAttributeText('attributecode')` method to get the frontend value for any attribute.